after Installing Packages and run composer require logger
command  composer require logger work properly

but after i do  git status show me
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
        deleted:    my_project_directory

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        modified:   composer.json
        modified:   composer.lock
        modified:   config/bundles.php
        modified:   symfony.lock

then i write git add composer.json composer.lock config/bundles.php symfony.lock config/packages/monolog.yaml  and show me this error
warning: in the working copy of 'composer.json', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'composer.lock', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'config/bundles.php', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'symfony.lock', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'config/packages/monolog.yaml', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it

how i can fix this?

https://docs.github.com/de/get-started/getting-started-with-git/configuring-git-to-handle-line-endings

It's not really an error, it's more of a notification. It won't interrupt whatever it is you are doing.
Check in your console:
git config core.autocrlf

This will return either "false", "input" or "true"; "true" and "false" being the wrong values. Change it to "input" by typing:
git config --global core.autocrlf input

Replace --global by --local if you want to set it only for the active repository
